# Finding Path (like Dijkstra) in Relation with SQL

Tags: sql, graph

i'm quite new to SQL so here's my question:

Let's assume we have a Table T with columns A and B

```
A | B
1 | 2
2 | 3
4 | 6
3 | 5 
3 | 8
7 | 8
```

Now there is a path between A and B. I'll just call them nodes for now. You can get from node A to B but not from B to A unless there is are rows like:

```
1 | 2
2 | 1
```

But in our example we don't have any circles.

My goal is to find the ends of a path starting in 1. 
I used recursion query like:

```
with rec (start, end)  as (
    (select A, B 
    from T 
    where A = '1')
    union all
    ( select A, B 
     from T, rec
     where T.A = re.end
    )
)
```

which result in rec output (`select * from rec`)looking like this:

```
1 | 2
2 | 3 
3 | 5
3 | 8
```

I'm struggling to retrieve start and ends only from this output

smth like

```
1 | 5,8
```

Can someone help? 
If I can retrieve start and end, I won't need the recursion cause I'm only interested in these Nodes (not the path)

//edited, now more accurate

Comment: I know my examples aren't accurate but I think you guys can get the point.

Comment: Recursion is a product specific feature. What is your DBMS?

Comment: I'm using a "with ... ()" statement but recursion is not my problem (my DBMS definitely supports it). I just need a way to get the start and the ends of that path and I cant think of any Query that would fit

Comment: Please update the question. Provide essential data, query and describe what is the problem exactly.

Comment: Done. As I said the recursion is not necessary if you can solve the main question of how to get the ends of a path beginning in X. Maybe if will make things easier since it kicks out all unimportant rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided no circle exists, using Sql Server 2017

```
with rec (root, start, [end])  as (
    (select A root, A , B 
    from T 
    where A = '1')
    union all
    ( select root, A, B 
     from T
     join rec ON T.A = rec.[end]
    )
)
select root A, string_agg([end], ',') B
from rec
where not exists (select 1 from T where T.A = rec.[end])
group by root;
```

When using another DBMS use different string aggregation, all the rest should work as is.

[Db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b8a09732a4734320b06e29e8a5bed349)

Comment: thanks, I've totaly forgot that I could use an attribute to store the root :)
Can you think of any way to solve this problem without recursion (with Table T only and standard sql statements)?

Comment: @bigsmokecriminal , Generally recursion is inevitable. If the number of tree levels is strictly less then N, one can use N left joins.